# UV radiation simulation in ANSYS

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, simulation, ansys, radiation

I am setting up a simulation in fluent to estimate the UV radiation dosage of an air stream passing through a cylindrical duct with the UV source in line with its main axis. It is a very simple system, one inlet and one outlet.

[image]

I've done simple simulations involving convection heat transfer but never one with radiation. As you can see the duct behaves as a mirror and reflects the radiation internally which makes solving this example by hand rather complicated.
Can anyone suggest the best way to go about setting the simulation specially the radiation boundary conditions? I know the total UV radiation of the lamp as well as the W/cm^2 output, i also have an estimation of the lamp's surface temperature.

In the end my simulation should provide a similar result to this:

[image]

Any tips would be very useful, Thank you very much in advance